# nginx enables https on port 80 and 8080 only

Tags: nginx

I know almost nothing about nginx, please help me to see if it can be achieved ?

1. A public network IP with only 80 and 8080 ports open, Such as `182.148.???.135`
2. A domain name with an SSL certificate, Such as `mini.????.com`
3. This domain name can resolve to this IP.

#### Using the above conditions, how to enable https ? So that I can pass visit `https://mini.????.com` to the target server `182.148.???.135`

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi @Ethical Hacker Minh, I want to visit https://mini.????.com to the target server 182.148.???.135

Comment: With or without nginx, if you can't open port 443 on your server, the only thing you can get to work is `https://mini.????.com:80/` or `https://mini.????.com:8080/`. If you don't specify the port explicitly, any browser will assume it is 443, the default port for https protocol.

Comment: Is it possible ```http://mini.????.com``` to ```https://mini.????.com:8080``` to ```182.148.???.135```

Answer (score 0):

Just came accross an issue. Doesn’t matter if its a local setup or one with a domain name.

When you create a symbolic frpom sites-available to sites-enabled you have to use the whole path to each location.

e.g. you can’t

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
ln -s monitor ../sites-enabled/
```

It has to be:

```
ln -s  /etc/nginx/sites-available/monitor  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Inside /etc/nginx/sites-available you should have just edited the default file to change the root web folder you specified and left the server name part alone. Restart nginx, should work fine. You don’t need to specify the IP of your droplet. That’s the whole purpose of the default file.

You only need to copy the default file and change server names when you want to set up virtual hosts.

Comment: Oh, you misunderstood my question, I want to know how to enable https

Comment: Ugh, [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) might help you.